Are there any spring properties to set defaults for spring webclient?
I was wondering if there exists something like
spring.webclient.connectionPoolSize=100
spring.webclient.readTimeOut=1s

and other similar properties in the same way we configure default kafka or jdbc properties through the application.properties file.
Currently, all I can find is the option to create a custom connector and supply it with a user defined httpClient with all the desired settings to webclient like so :
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();

It doesn't seem the configuration can be externalized without writing some boilerplate code.
